# Proteus - Power Plane fails to connect

Tags: proteus

I have a 4 layer board, with Power and Ground being the inner planes. 
I have a component which connects to the netlist AVDD 
The power plane has:

Net: AVDD=POWER

Layer/Colour: Power

Boundary: Default

Relief: RELIEF

Type: Solid

Clearance: 10th

With boxes Relieve Pins and Supress islands both checked

I connect a via between top copper (component side) and Power:

From: Top Copper

To: POWER

Style: DEFAULT

Net: NONE

This via does not connect to the AVDD on my component - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the via gets its net from the component it is connected to, so the track comes first and the via to link to the pwr/gnd must come after that. Putting a via in first does not work, although putting a lone pad, and editing it, does.